Chrome Dev Tools: Can't make live CSS edits to nested media queries
Nested media queries cannot be live edited in Chrome Dev Tools.
Let's say I have this CSS:
.grid {
    display: grid;
​    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);​
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .grid {
​        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);​
    }
}

​This CSS I can live edit just fine, for example changing the number of grid columns for the 1024px breakpoint.
However, if I instead do this (which is much nicer to work with):
.grid {
    display: grid;
​    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);​

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
​        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);​
    }
}

Then if I try to do live edits to the 1024px breakpoint in Dev Tools, nothing happens. The changes made immediately revert to their previous state, and are not reflected on the page.
Is this a known issue, and can anything be done about it (except for Google fixing it)?
Edit: Workaround found, see answer below.

It's a bug. You can report it in https://crbug.com if it's not fixed in Chrome Canary and not yet reported.

I found a workaround:
While this does not work (CSS cannot be live-edited):
.grid {
    display: grid;
​    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);​

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
​        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);​
    }
}

...this (which means the same thing but is just a bit more verbose) DOES work (CSS can be live-edited):
.grid {
    display: grid;
​    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);​

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        & {
​            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);​
        }
    }
}


Great workaround.  & is another idea borrowed from preprocessing a while back.
